# How to remove "Writing library" from .mp3?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, mp3, lame

I am trying to encode .**mp3** without encoder information ("Writing library"), but it fails.
I already try:

1. `ffmpeg -i test.wav -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 test.mp3`
2. `ffmpeg -i test.wav -write_xing 0 -id3v2_version 0 test.mp3`

and

3. `ffmpeg -i test.wav -write_xing 0 -id3v2_version 0 -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 test.mp3`

but "*Writing library : LAME3.100*" **still exists**...

```
General
Complete name               : C:\Users\User\Videos\test.mp3
Format                      : MPEG Audio
File size                   : 1 010 KiB
Duration                    : 1 min 4 s
Overall bit rate mode       : Constant
Overall bit rate            : 128 kb/s
Writing library             : LAME3.100

Audio
Format                      : MPEG Audio
Format version              : Version 1
Format profile              : Layer 3
Format settings             : Joint stereo / MS Stereo
Duration                    : 1 min 4 s
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Sampling rate               : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                  : 41.667 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 1 010 KiB (100%)
Writing library             : LAME3.100
```

**What do I need to do to remove this metadata?**
(Writing library)

Comment: Why would you want to remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `-metadata 'Writing library'=''`  to whatever you do, just before output filename.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -metadata 'Writing library'='' test.mp3
```

Comment: I add this:
**ffmpeg -i test.wav -metadata "Writing library"="" test.mp3**

But this doesn't remove "Writing library" metadata. And if I try to put an any value there (for example: **ffmpeg -i test.wav -metadata "Writing library"="grk03hk3gs0677777sss" test.mp3**), then ffmpeg will just add one more line (Writing library             : grk03hk3gs0677777sss):

Overall bit rate            : 128 kb/s
Writing library             : LAME3.100
Writing library             : grk03hk3gs0677777sss

Comment: @WarNight Very strange... For me works well, and so says ffmpeg documentation:
__It is also possible to delete metadata by using an empty value.__